# Highlighting the maximal value of a column with conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a simple column of numbers here (A2 to A10) in which I want to highlight the maximum value in that column. Instinctively I went to conditional formatting and learnt that the formula for it was `=A2=MAX($A$2:$A$10)` applied to A2:A10. I'm glad it works hassle-free, but I would not have thought to put the A2 in the front and have $'s, why are those necessary?

I would have been banging my head against a wall with just `=MAX(A2:A10)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: it can be simpler than that. Pick "Format cells if... *Is equal to*" and put `=MAX(A$2:A$10)`, and you'll have the same result.

[image: formatting]

Why dollar signs? Because without them, the references are relative. The formula that you enter is assumed to be designed for the upper left corner of the range being formatted; for all other cells in the range, it will be interpreted using relative references. That is, if you compare A2 to `=MAX(A2:A10)`, then A3 will be compared to `=MAX(A3:A11)`, A4 to `=MAX(A4:A12)`, and so on. This is not what you wanted.

(You will appreciate the relative nature of references when you decide to format cells in A if their values are equal / less than /greater than the corresponding values in B.)

There is no reason to put $ before A since the formatting is only applied within column A. Both $A and A mean the same column in this case.

---

Why would someone suggest `=A2=MAX($A$2:$A$10)`? Because they are used to conditional formatting using custom formulas. A custom formula needs to return True or False. So, the equality A2=MAX($A$2:$A$10) is checked, and the result is returned as True and False.

Comment: precise answer as usual, thanks:)